# Run time error while connecting to Azure using EF Code first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database

This error has me absolutely stumped

Let me explain the scenario

I have the following projects in a solution

1. A Web service project - Empty MVC
2. A Plain POCO class with a definition for a table (single table)
3. A project with a class file derived from DBContext

I am trying to use EF 6.0 to create / update a table on a database on Azure.

Note:

> - The solution is compiling OK
> - I have installed EF 6 into 3 above
> - I have added a connection string (below) into both the web.config file of the web service project and the app.config file of the class
>     derived from DBcontext

```
<add name="sometablecontext" connectionString="Server=tcp:someservername.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=databasename;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=username;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

- I have enabled-migrations at the package manager console - no issues there
- When I get to adding a migration I get the following run time error

PM> add-migration IntitalTableCreation

```
  System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 
  predicate)
     at  

 System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderManifestExtensions.GetStoreTypeFromName(D
   bProviderManifest providerManifest, String name)
   at 
 System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.Primiti
 vePropertyConfiguration.ConfigureColumn(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, 
 DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at 
 System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.Primiti
 vePropertyConfiguration.Configure(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, 
 DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride, Boolean 
 fillFromExistingConfiguration)
    at 
 System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.Primiti
 vePropertyConfiguration.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Configure>b__3(Tuple`2 pm)
    at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 
 ts, Action`1 action)
    at 
 System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.Primiti
 vePropertyConfiguration.Configure(IEnumerable`1 propertyMappings, 
 DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride, Boolean 
 fillFromExistingConfiguration)
    at 
 System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.StructuralTypeConfigur
 ation.ConfigurePropertyMappings(IList`1 propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest 
 providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride)
    at 
 System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguratio
 n.ConfigurePropertyMappings(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, EntityType 
 entityType, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride)
    at 
 System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguratio
 n.Configure(EntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, 
 DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
    at 
 System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure
 EntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, ICollection`1 entitySets, 
 DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
    at 
 System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure
 (DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
    at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest 
 providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String migrationName, String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Sequence contains no matching element
```

I understand that this is an error when you use something like first() instead of firstordefault().

> What could possible be wrong?
>
> Any help would be appreciated.
>
> Any queries are welcome

Is there something wrong with the provider name in the connection string??

Answer (score 0):

Ugh! I don't know how i made such a stupid mistake!

In my poco class I was trying to map a byte to a bit!

AS follows!

```
[Column(TypeName = "BIT")]
public virtual System.Byte Status { get; set; }
```

As soon as i corrected this error, the problem was resolved